# How to capture the value on EOFError with raw_input in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7

**raw data:**

```
k = {u'description': u'First Contentful Paint marks the time at which the first text or image is painted. [Learn more].', u'title': u'First Contentful Paint', u'score': 1.0, u'scoreDisplayMode': u'numeric', u'displayValue': u'0.5\xa0s', u'id': u'first-contentful-paint'}
```

**snippet:**

```
data = k["lighthouseResult"]["audits"]["first-contentful-paint"]["displayValue"]

try:
    val = raw_input(data.encode("utf-8"))
except EOFError:
    print("skipped")

print "output: " + val
```

In the above snippet, how can I store the results in `val`; the step is skipped when there is a `EOFError` on line `val = raw_input(data.encode("utf-8"))`

Here is the actual output I get, and I am unable to store the values `x.x s` in a variable

```
0.5 sskipped

output:
```

**Expected:**

```
output: 0.5s
```

Python version: `2.7`

Comment: I don't understand why you need `eval` at all. Why not just `val = raw_input(...)`?

Comment: And why have you tagged this as python-3.x when it is clearly Python 2?

Comment: @DanielRoseman `val = raw_input(...)` did not work in my case, tats why I used eval.

Comment: @DanielRoseman do you know how to store the value on EOFerror

Comment: @DanielRoseman I believe, it is a common question that can be applied to all python users; tats why I tagged python3

Comment: How does `arr` look like, can you add ad example, also is this for python2 or python3? Also `raw_input` is not present in Python3, hence the question from Daniel @PrashanthSams

Comment: What do you mean, "did not work"? *What happened*?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh this is for Python2; updating the arr in question

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh yes, raw_input is not in Python 3; I use Python 2; mentioned python 2 in question

Comment: Please provide actual values in the array, and not placeholders like value1 value2 etc

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh I get something like u`"0.5\xa0s"`; tats why I extracted them using `eval` and `unicode`

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh my question is not about that; the question is, how to capture the value when there is an error; I can see the value in console but I am unable to store it; can you please help

Comment: Can you show a sample run of your input and mention where it throws `EOFError` Also show us the actual `arr` instead of `[value1, value2, value3, value4]`, because we don't want guess what `value1` , `value2` etc are?

Comment: sample dict from where I extracted the data `{u'description': u'First Contentful Paint marks the time at which the first text or image is painted. [Learn more].', u'title': u'First Contentful Paint', u'score': 1.0, u'scoreDisplayMode': u'numeric', u'displayValue': u'0.5\xa0s', u'id': u'first-contentful-paint'}`

data manipulation here:
`value1 = k["lighthouseResult"]["audits"]["first-contentful-paint"]["displayValue"]
value2 = k["lighthouseResult"]["audits"]["first-meaningful-paint"]["displayValue"]`

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh would be great if you give me some simplification on this as I am new to python; but my actual concern is, storing values

Comment: All that information is unrelated to what is actually mentioned in the question, can you reformat the question to be more clear on what the input and what the output is?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh I agree with you; updated the question; should be more clear now

Comment: @DanielRoseman hope the question is clear now; can you please help. thank you

Comment: think you want to decode '0.5\xa0s', I have added an answer on how to do it, please take a look! @PrashanthSams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to decode `'0.5\xa0s'`  is to use [unicode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unicode) builtin function to convert this to unicode and tell it to ignore non `utf-8` characters, and convert it to string

```
>>> a = '0.5\xa0s'
>>> str(unicode(a, errors='ignore'))
'0.5s'
```

Answer (score 0):

As Devesh explained, I ignored the errors to get rid of the issue that I was facing.

```
>>> a = '0.5\xa0s'
>>> a.encode(encoding="ascii", errors="ignore")
'0.5s'
```